# How can I run Ubuntu withouth affecting my existing operating system?

Tags: windows, 18.04, windows-xp

I have downloaded ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso and would like to run from cd without destroying my existing Windows System.

I burned the iso file to a dvd. What do I do next? What do I do with this iso file?

Comment: Since you are using Windows XP, I’d like to ask: Is your computer really able to run 64-bit binaries (like in amd64)? Many computers from the XP era need 32-bit binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this procedure](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) to complete the installation from a DVD or USB flash drive, or to try Ubuntu without installing. In step 6, you should see an option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

In short, here's what you need to do:

Put the Ubuntu DVD into your optical/DVD drive. Then restart your computer. As soon as your computer boots you'll see the welcome window.

From there, you can select your language from a list on the left and choose between either installing Ubuntu directly, or trying the desktop first (if you like what you see, you can also install Ubuntu from this mode too).

Comment: Gave up on trying to download to XP enviornment, just ordered the ready made DVD fom Ubuntu.